# iPhone app using openAL works in simulator, but not on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, frameworks, openal

I added the openAL framework to my app and I am using the sound engine that is in the demo CrashLanding.  It works just fine on the simulator, but when I build it for my device, I get errors.  It looks like the framework isn't added.  I've tried: restarting xcode; delete the framework and add it in again; cleaning the target; restart the computer.  It still works on the simulator, but the device setting won't even compile.  Does anyone have any other ideas or am I doing something wrong?

Here's a more specific error, there are 17 right now:

"_alSourcePlay", referenced from:

SoundEngineEffect::PlaybackProc(void*)   in SoundEngine.o

SoundEngineEffect::Start()      in SoundEngine.o

Also, CrashLanding runs fine on my device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the OpenAL framework you added.

Go to one of the other frameworks in your project, say UIKit, right-click and "reveal in finder".

Drag the OpenAL you find there from the Finder window into XCode under Frameworks.

Now it will probably work... sometimes when you say "Add Existing Frameworks" it seems to choose a wrong directory, and you are probably adding the OS X OpenAL framework (which is fine for the simulator).